# How to run a query on the resultant table of an inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following statement that with a inner join creates a table. I now want to filter the inner joined table with a right function how do I do this?
see the right function with -- in front.

```
SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText --where RIGHT(filename,6) = 'SLDDRW'
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID;
```

Comment: just add another select and wrap the inner join in parentheses

Comment: @dunno can you demonstrate this as an answer? I have tried but get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this ?

```
SELECT Documents.Filename , VariableValue.ValueText 
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN VariableValue ON Documents.DocumentID = VariableValue.DocumentID
where RIGHT(Documents.filename,6) = 'SLDDRW';
```